# Android video crash

Tags: android, video

When I tried to slide on the screen during 10 sec. during video playing, I got an error ‘Activity MyActivity (in application MyActivity) is not responding’. That error showed on Android 3.2.1 (on Android 2.3.3 – all OK).

```
AppWindowToken{4171c010 token=ActivityRecord{40a4b008 com.MyActivity/.Home}}.  5018.0ms since event, 5004.9ms since wait started
01-10 14:08:31.280 I/WindowManager(  142): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{4171c010 token=ActivityRecord{40a4b008 com.MyActivity/.Home}}
01-10 14:08:31.310 I/Process (  142): Sending signal. PID: 4027 SIG: 3
01-10 14:08:31.310 I/dalvikvm( 4027): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
01-10 14:08:31.320 I/dalvikvm( 4027): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-10 14:08:31.320 I/Process (  142): Sending signal. PID: 142 SIG: 3
01-10 14:08:31.320 I/dalvikvm(  142): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
01-10 14:08:31.350 I/dalvikvm(  142): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-10 14:08:31.350 I/Process (  142): Sending signal. PID: 224 SIG: 3
01-10 14:08:31.350 I/dalvikvm(  224): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
01-10 14:08:31.360 I/dalvikvm(  224): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-10 14:08:31.360 I/Process (  142): Sending signal. PID: 200 SIG: 3
01-10 14:08:31.360 I/dalvikvm(  200): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
01-10 14:08:31.370 I/dalvikvm(  200): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-10 14:08:31.550 D/dalvikvm(  142): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2091K, 40% free  17467K/28679K, paused 5ms+8ms
01-10 14:08:31.690 D/dalvikvm(  142): GC_EXPLICIT freed 303K, 40% free 17465K/28679K, paused 3ms+5ms
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142): ANR in com.MyActivity (com.MyActivity/.Home)
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142): Load: 0.41 / 0.3 / 0.18
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142): CPU usage from 26289ms to 0ms ago with 99% awake:
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   22% 89/mediaserver: 17% user + 4.6% kernel / faults: 2598 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   14% 4027/com.MyActivity: 11% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 1460 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   8.1% 195/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 8.1% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   7.4% 142/system_server: 2.2% user + 5.1% kernel / faults: 96 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   2% 86/surfaceflinger: 0.7% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 2 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   1.8% 4000/kworker/u:1: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   1.7% 2307/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   1.4% 1713/kworker/u:3: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.5% 62/kinteractiveup: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.5% 3541/kworker/u:2: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.4% 224/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 1 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.3% 88/drmserver: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.3% 200/com.android.systemui: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 32 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0% 222/com.android.launcher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 197 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.2% 2954/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.2% 3584/kworker/1:1: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0% 322/android.process.media: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 69 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.1% 128/irq/182-3d: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0.1% 194/dhd_watchdog: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0% 1583/avp_svc_thread: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0% 209/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   0% 2556/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142): 30% TOTAL: 16% user + 11% kernel + 0.4% iowait + 1.7% softirq
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142): CPU usage from 417ms to 950ms later:
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   20% 89/mediaserver: 20% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):     7.2% 4075/TimedEventQueue: 7.2% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):     7.2% 4081/AudioTrackThrea: 7.2% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):     3.6% 138/Playback Thread: 3.6% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):     1.8% 4071/TimedEventQueue: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   10% 142/system_server: 0% user + 10% kernel / faults: 1 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):     7.2% 173/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 7.2% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):     3.6% 174/InputReader: 1.8% user + 1.8% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   1.1% 86/surfaceflinger: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):     1.1% 118/SurfaceFlinger: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   1.2% 195/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   1.8% 1713/kworker/u:3: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):   1.8% 4027/com.MyActivity: 0% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 5 minor
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142):     1.8% 4027/com.MyActivity: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.280 E/ActivityManager(  142): 23% TOTAL: 12% user + 10% kernel
01-10 14:08:32.290 W/webview ( 4027): Got ACTION_DOWN but still waiting on stale event. Catching up.
01-10 14:08:32.360 D/dalvikvm( 4027): GC_CONCURRENT freed 412K, 7% free 7147K/7623K, paused 2ms+8ms
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_DOWN received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(0) received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(0) received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_MOVE received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_POINTER_UP(0) received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_POINTER_UP(0) received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(0) received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_MOVE received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(0) received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_MOVE received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_POINTER_UP(0) received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:32.590 W/webview ( 4027): Stale touch event ACTION_POINTER_UP(0) received from webcore; ignoring
01-10 14:08:35.430 W/ActivityManager(  142):   Force finishing activity com.MyActivity/.Home
01-10 14:08:35.470 I/Process (  142): Sending signal. PID: 4027 SIG: 9
01-10 14:08:35.470 I/ActivityManager(  142): Killing com.MyActivity (pid=4027): user's request
01-10 14:08:35.490 I/AwesomePlayer(   89): reset
01-10 14:08:35.490 I/WindowManager(  142): WIN DEATH: Window{41363c38 com.MyActivity/com.MyActivity.Home paused=true}
01-10 14:08:35.490 I/ActivityManager(  142): Process com.MyActivity (pid 4027) has died.
01-10 14:08:35.500 I/AwesomePlayer(   89): cancel player events
```

Code:

```
private void showVideo(String url) {
    if (videoView != null) 
    return;

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    findViewById(R.id.close_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.root_view));
    Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoView = null;
            findViewById(R.id.close_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Activity MyActivity (in application MyActivity) is not responding" means that you are taking too much time on the main application thread. If you are trying to use the emulator, it may simply be that your PC is not fast enough to run the 3.2 emulator very well.

Otherwise, you will simply need to determine where you are spending your time on the main application thread, whether using logging to LogCat, Traceview, `StrictMode`, or other means.

Comment: @Dale: That may be true but does not change my answer.